# Problems with the CTAN website - while the "Default Skin" is in use, other skins can't be selected to be applied

Tags: ctan

Usually I use the Chromium web browser.

The last time I visited https://ctan.org, everything was displayed in the Halloween theme.  Since this irritated me (among other things due to my visual impairment), to get rid of that Halloween design, under the heading "Default Skin" I clicked the link with the circled small wedge pointing to the right and the writing "Default Skin".

Now I'm shown a default skin with many things missing the clickable link. For example, on the subpage "Settings/Skins" (https://ctan.org/user/settings) I can't click on any skin to have it applied.  I would like to have the skin "Gray" applied. I am used to it. But while the "Default Skin" is in use, other skins can't be selected to be applied.

What can I do?

(Today I use the Firefox web browser as today with the Firefox web browser the page is displayed with the "Gray Skin".)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

When you're in the default settings, it can't find `skin.css`, and the styling breaks.  This means that the styling that shows each of the skins is clickable goes away, and they all appear to be regular text.

But that's only the appearance.  I'm still able to click "Gray" next to the image of the skin, and I get the Gray skin without any problems.  (And if that doesn't work, I can right click the gray, inspect the element, and read that it's executing the javascript `PortalSkin.set('gray');`, so you could run that in your console.)

You can also go into `chrome://settings/cookies/detail?site=ctan.org` (can't hyperlink that, you'll need to copy/paste) and delete the cookie related to the skin.  This seems to get me back to the Gray skin instead of the default, so everything works.

Comment: Using the default-skin I can click the example-image for each skin in order to have it displayed in a separate window. But on my system clicking, e.g., the textual phrase "Gray" has no effect as long as the add-blocker is not deactivated. When deactivated, then you can click textual phrases and this way apply skins. I wonder why the non-deactivated add-blocker does apply only while the default-skin is selected but doesn't apply while other skins are selected.  Skin-dependent add-blocking seems like an amusing feature. :-) Maybe I will bother the guys who develop the add-blocker in use :-)

Comment: @UlrichDiez It's conceivable that the ad-blocker doesn't like an `onclick` that's not styled to look like a hyperlink.  That's the best guess I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

**I also stumbled across this.**
After selecting the default skin, in the settings-page (https://ctan.org/user/settings) the various skins were displayed/shown/listed, but none of them could be clicked to be applied.
Seems the problem occurs only while the default skin is in use.
(Maybe the problem is related to script- and/or add-blockers in use.)

**Here's how I got around it:**

**Method 1:**

**In the Internet browser, delete all cookies belonging to https://ctan.org.**
(Chromium browser: Browse to the settings-page, https://ctan.org/user/settings, and click with the right mouse button on the window of the Chromium browser where the page is displayed. A context menu pops up. In this context menu, at the very bottom, with the left mouse button click on "Inspect". (You can also use the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd>.) The window splits in two. On the left side the web-page is still displayed as usual. On the right side you see the source code of the page and tables with lists of properties of elements to be examined. The header of the right side consists of a horizontal menu bar—items of that menu bar are: Elements/​Console/​Sources/​Network/​Performance/​Memory/​Application/​Security/​Lighthouse. There is a menu item "Application".  Select it by clicking with the left mouse button. (Maybe you have to click the » sign in the menu bar with the left mouse-button to get this menu item displayed.) The menu "Application" opens up. Under "Storage" click the item "Cookies" with the left mouse-button. Thereupon a list with entries folds out downward. In this list, right-click the entry "https://ctan.org".  In the context menu that opens, with the left mouse-button click on the entry "clear". Then close the right side of the split window by clicking with the left mouse-button on the X symbol at the right of the menu-bar where "Application" was clicked.)

**Reload the settings-page https://ctan.org/user/settings.**
Usually you will see the Gray theme again.
On Halloween you will see the Halloween theme again.
With these themes all skins on the settings page are clickable and selectable.

**After scrolling so that you see the top of the page, at the top right you find a menu-bar Login/Join/Settings/Help.**
**In this menu-bar click on "Settings" with the left mouse button.**

**Now you can choose a skin. E.g. under the heading "Color-based Skins" the skin "Gray".**

---

**Method 2:**

**In the cookie of https://ctan.org change value of the key `skin`, which is empty when the default-skin is in use, to `gray`.**

Chromium browser: Browse to https://ctan.org, and click with the right mouse button on the window of the Chromium browser where the page is displayed. A context menu pops up. In this context menu, at the very bottom, with the left mouse button click on "Inspect". (You can also use the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd>.) The window splits in two. On the left side the web-page is still displayed as usual. On the right side you see the source code of the page and tables with lists of properties of elements to be examined. The header of the right side consists of a horizontal menu bar—items of that menu bar are: Elements/​Console/​Sources/​Network/​Performance/​Memory/​Application/​Security/​Lighthouse. There is a menu item "Application".  Select it by clicking with the left mouse button. (Maybe you have to click the » sign in the menu bar with the left mouse-button to get this menu item displayed.) The menu "Application" opens up. Under "Storage" click the item "Cookies" with the left mouse-button. Thereupon a list with entries folds out downward. In this list, left-click the entry "https://ctan.org".  In the table with columns "Name", "Value", etc select the row where the column "Name" holds the value "skin" and in that row in the column "Value" type "gray" (without the surrounding quotes).
Then close the right side of the split window by clicking with the left mouse-button on the X symbol at the right of the menu-bar where "Application" was clicked.

**Reload the page https://ctan.org.**